# response not viewable in response body in rest client

Tags: json, rest, service, request, response

I am working on rest web service project currently actually in rest client in mozilla (chrome://restclient/content/restclient.html)it will get the {"id":"1234"} as request json and fetch the details of the id and provide all the details for id from database and convert into json array and finally its stored in responsetoservice object.

When i hit the service url the request reaches the server and status is 200 OK. But the response body in json is not visible in the response body(Raw) in the Rest client. But when i view the logs the json response is printed.

Can anyone help me regarding this stuck up on this. Please help me on why the response json is not viewable in rest client int mozilla

Comment: More details e.g. source code samples are required

Comment: Copy paste your url in firefox, then right click and select view source when request is processed, let know if you could find your response.

Comment: hi vinay, am running the url in this chrome://restclient/content/restclient.html

Comment: Hi  Alexander Elgin, responseToService = "{\"details\":"
         + responseFrmDB
         .getJSONArray(
           constants.id_DETAILS_DB)
           .toString() + "}"; this is the conversion of json array and when i run restclient chrome://restclient/content/restclient.html and give my url the method is post and request is single json {"id":"1234"} the request reaches the server and status is 200 ok and my json response is printed on logs. but i cannot view the response on the restclient ui response body can u please help

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be inability of your browser to parse and show the response, have a look at https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/Apr/01/Displaying-JSON-in-your-Browser

Comment: vinay any other way to do restclient other than mozilla and chrome
?